# UFW deletes all port specific ALLOW rules for IPV4

Tags: ufw

I have UFW configured as a firewall. Every now and then it deletes all ipv4 related rules (that are based on a port). The ALLOW lines that are based on an IP number are kept. Wondering what is doing this. Is there any housekeeping job that could be doing this?

Comment: Look at the logs: `journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/ufw` and `journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, assuming you're running Ubuntu.

Comment: The command using ufw has no entries and the Network-Manager version did nothing (No such file or directory).

Comment: I was looking again at this and found that there were no rules in the user.rules but only in the user6.rules. That made me think about the rules. I have a one strike out policy for everybody who tries to connect to my server. That means that I trigger on login failures and add a line to the firewall for the offending IP. This does only add rules but what if the number of rules is to much? Will accept rules (that move to the end because the offenders are added at the top) get lost? Currently I have 1991 (I seem to remember it was over 3000) rules that are a DENY. Any thoughts?

Comment: I added the disapeared rules via a oneliner and can now confirm that they are again present in user.rules. I tried the journalctl command with ufw but again no entries :(

Comment: Today the rules disappeared again and I went from over 2200 DENY rules to just over 714. It definitely is related to ufw updates. The new ones will build up again. Not worried about that but everytime this happens the ALLOW's are gone for IPV4 (because that is the larger file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed direction all together. I included ipset in ufw following the basic instructions in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/1571579) launchpad bug report. This solves my problem because ufw is now not called anymore to add an IP number to the blacklist.